# Create bins based on values for each group in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
test1<- data.frame("ID"= c("1","1","1", "2","2","2","3"), "TimeElapsed"=c(0,10,40,0,40,12,0))
```

Looks like:

```
ID  TimeElapsed
1    0
1    10
1    40
2    0
2    40
2    12
3    0
```

I want to create bins/sessions such that whenever time elapsed since last entry of an ID is more than 30, I want to start a new session for that ID. I use the following code from dplyr.

```
test1<-test1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
mutate(cut_session = (TimeElapsed > 30) + 1)
```

I get this result:

```
ID  TimeElapsed Session
1    0            1
1    10           1 
1    40           2 
2    0            1  
2    40           2
2    12           1     <- Doesn't work for this case         
3    0            1
```

I would like a solution that gives me session= 2 in the second last row since time elapsed is <30,
it should be the same session. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show the expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, we can use `cumsum` to add 1 whenever there the logical value is TRUE (TRUE/FALSE is 1/0).  After grouping by 'ID', get the cumulative sum of logical vector

```
library(dplyr)
test1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(cut_session = cumsum(TimeElapsed > 30))
```

---

How it works with `cumsum`?  Consider a logical vector

```
v1 <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
cumsum(v1)
#[1] 1 1 2 2 2
```

Whenever it hits a TRUE, 1 is added to the previous until it reaches the next TRUE values

If we need to add 1, then use

```
 cumsum(v1) + 1
```

Here, `+` is a symbol used explicitly for adding i.e. getting the sum of two objects on the lhs and rhs of it.  But, it would behave differently when there is an `NA` i.e.

```
NA + 1
```

returns NA

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the description too

Answer (score 0):

Use of `cumsum` is ideal here. I've *mutated* over two rows just to show you what's going on.

1. is `TimeElapsed` over 30?
2. Cumulatively count over 30s (adding `1` to make `1` the starting number)

```r
library(dplyr)

test1<- data.frame("ID"= c("1","1","1", "2","2","2","3"), "TimeElapsed"=c(0,10,40,0,40,12,0))

test1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(over30 = TimeElapsed > 30,
         cut_session = cumsum(over30) + 1)
#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>   ID    TimeElapsed over30 cut_session
#>   <chr>       <dbl> <lgl>        <dbl>
#> 1 1               0 FALSE            1
#> 2 1              10 FALSE            1
#> 3 1              40 TRUE             2
#> 4 2               0 FALSE            1
#> 5 2              40 TRUE             2
#> 6 2              12 FALSE            2
#> 7 3               0 FALSE            1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: OK, but without `+ 1`, nor any explanation as to what it's doing. @hashingdata is a new poster, so I assumed he may also be new to R, and therefore that some explanation would be beneficial.